# Error: Request failed with status code 401 axios in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am creating a login page using Laravel API and ReactJS front end. I am using [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) in ReactJS to parse the `username(email)` and `password`. The API for login is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login` which works correctly in postman `form-data`. But when I entered the `email` and the `password` in react front-end the echos is `Error: Request failed with status code 401.` This error throws by the catch function of axios. I am also using [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/querystring) npm also. So which throws this error?

**My React JS code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, CardBody, CardGroup, Col, Container, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Row } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import querystring from 'querystring';


class Login extends Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      email:"",
      password:""
    }
  }

  onClick(event)
  {
    var self = this;
    var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password,
    }
    //axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', payload) .then((response) => {}
    console.log("1. Hello before axios.post");
    //axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', payload)
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', querystring.stringify({payload}))

    .then((response) =>
    {
      console.log("2. Inside axios response");
      console.log(response);
      if(response.data.code == 200)
      {
        //Set localstorage:
        const userDetails = {userName: this.state.email}
        localStorage.setItem('userDetails', JSON.stringify(userDetails));

        console.log("Login successfull");
        return <Redirect to='/Master'  />

      }

      else if(response.data.code == 204)
      {
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert(response.data.success)
      }

      else if(response.data.code == 401)
      {
        alert(response.data.success)
      }

      else
      {
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
      }
    })

    .catch(function (error)
    {
      console.log("The error is : " + error);
    });
}
  render()
  {
    return (
      <div className="app flex-row align-items-center">
        <Container>
          <Row className="justify-content-center">
            <Col md="8">
              <CardGroup>
                <Card className="p-4">
                  <CardBody>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    <p className="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="icon-user" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                      <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <InputGroupText>
                          <i className="icon-lock" />
                        </InputGroupText>
                      </InputGroupAddon>
                      <Input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </InputGroup>
                    <Row>
                      <Col xs="6">
                        <Button color="primary" className="px-4" onClick={this.onClick}>
                          Login
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                      <Col xs="6" className="text-right">
                        <Button color="link" className="px-0">
                          Forgot password?
                        </Button>
                      </Col>
                    </Row>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
                <Card
                  className="text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none"
                  style={{ width: 44 + "%" }}
                >
                  <CardBody className="text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Sign up</h2>
                      <p>
                        Are you a new user to the Restaurant system? Hooray now , you can create an account...
                      </p>
                      <Button color="primary" className="mt-3" active>
                        Register Now!
                      </Button>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </CardGroup>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

The following is the Laravel API login code which requires the `email` and `password`

**Laravel login API code**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; 
use App\User; 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; 
use Validator;
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    public $successStatus = 200;

    public function login()
    { 
        if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')]))
        {
            $user = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
            return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus);
        } 

        else
        { 
            return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorized'], 401); 
        } 
    }
}
```

**Update**

As [Alex](https://github.com/alsofronie) says [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960#issuecomment-309287911) I changed `console.log("The error is : " + error);`
 as `console.log("The error is : " + error.response);` in `catch` function. It echos `The error is : [object Object]`.

Answer (score 18):

**This is correct and working code solution**

*The correct way to set headers in Axios*

```
axios.post('http://10.0.1.14:8001/api/logout',request_data, {
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
          },      
      })      
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response',response.data)

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert('error',error.response)
        dispatch(userUpdateProfileFail())

      })

  // console.log('----cheers---------',data)
dispatch(userUpdateProfileSuccess(data))
```

cheers********

Comment: How are we supposed to get the token without logging in?

Answer (score 6):

You can post axios data by using [FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) like :

And then add the fields to the form you want to send :

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.set('email',this.state.email);
bodyFormData.set('password', this.state.password);
```

And then you can use axios post method (You can amend it accordingly)

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login',
    data: bodyFormData,
    config: { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }}
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        //handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        //handle error
        console.log(response);
    });
```

Comment: where should I first three fields? So, what about the `payload` variable in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Problem with me was Invalid `Token` so check token ,`authorization` and `unauthenticated`.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting GitHub API in my application and faced the same issue. My API access token had been expired so the API wasn't sending any results, that's why there was nothing to iterate in my app. I created a new token from settings of [GitHub](https://github.com/) and used that while sending the requests. The issue was resolved.