# How to get historical data from barchart web using node js

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios

I'm trying to get historical data from the website
https://www.barchart.com/stocks/quotes/AAPL/price-history/historical

The data displayed on the screen is loaded from a json obtained from an api.
This is the API url:
https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/historical/get?symbol=AAPL&fields=tradeTime.format(m%2Fd%2FY)%2CopenPrice%2ChighPrice%2ClowPrice%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2Cvolume%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType&type=eod&orderBy=tradeTime&orderDir=desc&limit=65&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description&raw=1

I have tried doing an api request with axios, but all I get is

**AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401**

**CODE**

```
const axios = require('axios');

const urlAPI = 'https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/historical/get?symbol=AAPL&fields=tradeTime.format(m%2Fd%2FY)%2CopenPrice%2ChighPrice%2ClowPrice%2ClastPrice%2CpriceChange%2CpercentChange%2Cvolume%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType&type=eod&orderBy=tradeTime&orderDir=desc&limit=65&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description&raw=1';

axios.get(urlAPI)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 401 is auth error. You need to include token or email & password while sending request. [Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495922/error-request-failed-with-status-code-401-axios-in-react-js)